# I have the exception as soon as shutting down my workbench

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

```
!SESSION 2010-10-05 15:59:54.026 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ko_KR
Framework arguments:  -product JobSchedulerClient.product
Command-line arguments:  -product JobSchedulerClient.product -data C:\Users\Tom\workspace/../runtime-JobSchedulerClient.product -dev file:C:/Users/Tom/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/JobSchedulerClient.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2010-10-05 16:03:50.567
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.disposeParent(EditorSashContainer.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.dispose(PartSashContainer.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.dispose(EditorSashContainer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.dispose(EditorAreaHelper.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.dispose(WorkbenchPage.java:1822)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.closeAllPages(WorkbenchWindow.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.hardClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$0(WorkbenchWindow.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$5.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.WindowManager.close(WindowManager.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$18.run(Workbench.java:1105)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$15(Workbench.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$25.run(Workbench.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$0(WorkbenchWindow.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$5.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.handleShellCloseEvent(Window.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window$3.shellClosed(Window.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Decorations.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Decorations.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4162)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.data2tech.job.schedulerclient.Application.start(Application.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What platform (Windows 32/64?, Linux 32/64), Eclipse version (Ganymede, Helios? 32, 64?) are you using?

This bug was reported some time ago ([bug 263661](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=263661)), but was fixed in 3.4.1 and 3.5.

Make sure, on a 'x86_64' platform that you are using the right jdk for the right Eclipse distro (that is: a 32bit JDK with a 32bits Eclipse, or a 64bits JDK with a 64bits Eclipse)